# Bad frame for custom UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I try to make my own custom `UINavigationBar`, but I've a problem : with my solution, the `UINavigationBar` frame is in wrong position and it have wrong size... so it doesn't pass under statusbar.

So, this is my custom navigation bar :

```
import UIKit

class MainNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // not translucent
        translucent = false

        // set background colo
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 169/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1)

        // bar style
        barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black

        super.drawRect(rect)
    }
}
```

and I load it via an `UITabBarController` subclass (which loads a `UINavigationViewController` which loads my `UINavigationBar`) :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // init recipe
    let recipeItem = RecipeNavigationViewController(navigationBarClass: MainNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)

    [...]

    // view controllers displayed by the tab bar interface
    let controllers = [recipeItem, accountItem]
    self.viewControllers = controllers
}
```

So with this code, my custom `UINavigationBar` doesn't pass under statusbar.
What can I do?

Thank !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should override UINavigationBar. The properties you're trying to customize are already exposed by the UINavigationController so you can change that in your ViewController using self.navigationController.

Comment: Thanks ! I don't yet know good practices, but I will create a `BaseNavigationViewController` (in which one I will use `self.navigationBar`) that others `NavigationController` (one for each Tab of my `MainTabViewController`) inherit

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a subclass of UINavigationBar?
Can't you achieve the same thing with the AppearanceProxy ?

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.XXX,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.XXX]

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .XXX
```